# Read a MATLAB structure after calling MATLAB function from C#

Tags: c#, .net, matlab

I have a C# application that calls a MATLAB function (shown below). When the the MATLAB function returns just a double the code below works fine.

However I now have a MATLAB function that returns a structure (lets call it res_struct). The structure contains 13 fields. I am only interested in one field, `res_struct.success` which returns an integer. Is it possible to read this one field from a structure in C# from a MATLAB function?

```
         _matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
         _matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\My Directory\Functions\");

        // define the output
        object result = null;

        _matlab.Feval("my_function", 0, out result, "some_parameter");
        _matlab.Quit();           
        object[] res = result as object[];

        if ((double)res[0] == 1)
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Matlab Code ran successfully");
```